# Uploading image using Volley

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to upload an image from my application to my server using volley however it is failing to upload the image and is moving into the Volley Error response code. It's not giving me an error message or anything like that.

Here is my Android code.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                btnCamera.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void uploadImage(){

        JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
        String name = txtDesc.getText().toString();
        try{
            js.put("image", getStringImage(bitmap));
            js.put("name", name );

            Log.e("js", js.toString());
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,UPLOAD_URL, js,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            try{
                                String  strSuccess = response.getString("code");
                                Log.d(TAG, strSuccess);
                            } catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                            }



                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(ctx).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

PHP Code.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once 'db_config.php';
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);

$image= $data->image;
$name = $data->name;


 $actualpath = "http://46.101.2.231/FootballGroundGuide/stadium_images/$name" ;


 file_put_contents($actualpath,base64_decode($image));
 echo "Successfully Uploaded";




?>
```

Comment: Try checking the [return value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-put-contents-returnvalues) of `file_put_contents`. *This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.*

Comment: It's started saying SUCCESS which leads me to believe it's an issue with my PHP.

Comment: The file_put_contents method is returning false to the application @zwcloud

Comment: Fixed this issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this. Was using the full URL when i just needed to use "foldername/filename".